# How to access specific named list inside nested list in R

Tags: r

I have the following nested list:

```
foo <- list(list(x = 1:10, y = 11:25), list(x = 1:10, y = 100:110))
```

It looks like this:

```
> foo
[[1]]
[[1]]$x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[1]]$y
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25


[[2]]
[[2]]$x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]$y
 [1] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

What I want to do is only to access the `y` part of the list yielding in the object that contain this:

```
 [[1]]
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25


[[2]]
 [1] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply`

```
lapply(foo, `[[`, 'y')

#[[1]]
# [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25

#[[2]]
# [1] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

Or `pluck` from `rvest`

```
rvest::pluck(foo, 'y')
```

Answer (score 1):

One another option:

```
library(purrr)

map(foo, 'y')
[[1]]
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25

[[2]]
 [1] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat different solution is to transpose the list and access the slot:

```r
foo <- list(list(x = 1:10, y = 11:25), list(x = 1:10, y = 100:110))
purrr::transpose(foo)$y
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `base R` solution, using `unlist()` and `subset`

```
res <- subset(z<-unlist(foo,recursive = F),names(z)=="y")
```

such that

```
> res
$y
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25

$y
 [1] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```